# rotate an image with touch

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitouch

I making an app which sets the **sleep timer with a clock** .Basically it is  clock which has a single hand which user can move to set his sleep time .I tried to rotate the image with **uitouch** but it rotates from middle but i want it to rotate from the tip.Secondly i want that the image only rotates when user is touching the tip of the image  but in my project the image is also rotating when use touches any part of the screen.Also i want to rotate the image in both directions but in my project it moves only clockwise due to this method

`image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(image.transform, degreesToRadians(1));`

Can anybody give me hints or solutions about how can it be done?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //

        touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

        NSLog(@"began");

    }


    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        // get touch event

        [image.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0,0.0)];



        if ([touch view] == image) {
            image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(image.transform, degreesToRadians(1));

        //image.center = touchLocation;
    }

      }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        NSLog(@"end");



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rotate it the other way you just use:

```
image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(image.transform, degreesToRadians(1));
```

And to rotate form the tip you should use setAnchorPoint (like you used in your code, but i think you should do: [image setAnchorPoint]).

more on the subject: [setAnchorPoint for UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442349/setanchorpoint-for-uiimage)

Comment: Can you explain the whole process of doing this? I don't quite understand it from just the code, how do you set everything up to rotate the view?

Answer (score 2):

In detail, you can custom a rotateView,then:

1: In the delegate method of "touchesBegan", get initialPoint of finger and initialAngle.

2: During "touchesMoved",get the newPoint of finger:

```
CGPoint newPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
[self pushTouchPoint:thePoint date:[NSDate date]];
double angleDif = [self angleForPoint:newPoint] - [self angleForPoint:initialPoint];
self.angle = initialAngle + angleDif;
[[imageView layer] setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1)];
```

3: At last, in "touchesEnded" you can calculate final AngularVelocity.

If anything being confused, for more detail, you can write back.

Answer (score 0):

> *I tried to rotate the image with uitouch but it rotates from middle but i want it to rotate from the tip*

I dont know any way in SDK to rotate an element on its extreme end. If you want to have that effect take the clock handle image you have twice in length with half portion transparent. It is not a direct solution, but a workaround.

> *Also i want to rotate the image in both directions but in my project it moves only clockwise due to this method*

As per iOS developer documentation, a positive angle value specifies counterclockwise rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation.